# Contact Form 7 multi-column form error

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I was trying to implement multi column forms using contact form 7 plugin, by following the method described in this site using HTML markup method.

https://deliciousthemes.com/contact-form-7-fields-columns/

I have done it partially right, but the last signup button is messing up the layout in desktop view. However, everything is perfect in the mobile view.
Here is the link to my page.

https://medport.in/job-application-form/

I couldn't figure out where I went wrong. Please help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is mostly a CSS problem.

The container for your submit button is inside a paragraph tag which combined with your floating columns will break the way it looks.

Your website is using bootstrap so I would suggest using that instead.
Here is a guide: https://www.toptal.com/front-end/what-is-bootstrap-a-short-tutorial-on-the-what-why-and-how
(I am not affiliated with this website)

If you really want to use this method that you are currently using I would just add a CSS style to the p tag that will clear it away from the columns.
CSS to move it to the bottom of the form:

```
.wpcf7-form > p { clear: both; }
```